# Dojo tab is not loading external html

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer

When I click the second tab I want the callrecords.html code to be loaded but it isn't loading anything and the pane stays blank.  I'm somewhat of a noob and can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Also a side question.  Why do some code samples say dojoType and others use data-dojo-type.

```
<body class="tundra">

    <div class="formContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" >

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Advanced Search">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" 
                   size="30" /><br/>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" 
                   size="30" /><br/>
            <label for="middle_initial">Middle Initial:</label>
            <input type="text" name="middle_initial" id="middle_initial" 
                   size="1" /><br/>
        </div>

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Call Records" data-dojo-props='href:"modules/content_panes/callrecords.html", refresnOnShow:true'></div>

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Phones">
            <label for="home_phone">Home Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="home_phone" id="home_phone" 
                   size="30" /><br/>
            <label for="work_phone">Work Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="work_phone" id="work_phone" 
                   size="30" /><br/>
            <label for="cell_phone">Cell Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cell_phone" id="cell_phone" 
                   size="30" /><br/>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

callrecords.html

```
<h1>Tab 2</h1>

<p>I am tab 2. I was loaded externally as well.</p>
```

Comment: data-dojo-type is the new HTML5 syntax. Some examples use the old syntax, some the html5. http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/html5data-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things.

1) You have a typo: `refresnOnShow`.  Should be `refreshOnShow`.

2) `data-dojo-props` only works for Dojo > 1.7.  Are you using dojo 1.7 or greater?  If not, that won't work.

My suggestion is to try programmatically setting the pane href:

```
dijit.byId('tab2').attr('href', 'modules/content_panes/callrecords.html')
```

And see if that works.  The dojo 1.7 syntax is:

```
require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
var t = dijit.byId('tab2');
domAttr.set(t,'href','http://localhost:8080/vewpon/')
})
```

If the programmatic setting works, then you know its just something in your markup.

---

Update: For future reference, the Dojo 1.6 way of setting the type is: `dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"`

Comment: O geeze.  That's what I get for coding so late at night.  I am using 1.6 because I have had trouble finding documentation and blogs for 1.7.  How do you set properties on 1.6?  I see here http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/ that they use data-dojo-props on a 1.6 project around a third of the way down...

Comment: Never mind I got it working now.  Looks like it needs to be an HTML5 document for data-dojo-props to work not Dojo 1.7.